# I have a female fig black dress patterned slope only, long hair, intricate face

Tags: minifigure-identification

I'm looking to identify a Female minifig she has an open slope decorated skirt (no legs), long brown hair, big eyes! I think the body is wrong as it's plain black with standard yellow hands.

[image: Minifig for identification]

Comment: While there are some who might be able to do their magic with this description, there's more of us who could have a good shot if you'd include a picture. Is that an option?

Comment: @RSchulz I didn't even see a question...

Comment: Although the question could use some clarification, it looked like a fun challenge. I found one possible contender in my (non-exhaustive) search: [Narcissa Malfoy](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?M=hp126#T=S&O={%22iconly%22:0})

Comment: Thank you so much ! I'd  never have known Matthew. I did manage a screen shot in the end as puc was too big. Thank you as I can see I've wrong hair etc . Matthew, thanks for this as itbwas my first time here and I didn't know how it all worked.  Much appreciated

Answer (score 3):

- **Hair** is [Minifigure, Hair Long](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=40239). In Dark Brown color this was used by just one minifigure, the [Highland Battler](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=40239&colorID=120&in=A).
- **Face** seems to be one of two versions of Minifigure, Head Dual Sided Female, Dark Brown Eyebrows, Crow's Feet, Smile / Angry Pattern (HP Narcissa), [with Blocked Open Stud](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?id=102249) OR [with Hollow Stud](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?id=102469).
- **Torso** is unrecognizable as the picture isn't clear enough.
- **"Legs"** are [Slope 65 2 x 2 x 2 with Bottom Tube with Light Bluish Gray Inset Skirt Pattern](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3678bpb033) which, originally, belong to [Narcissa Malfoy](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?M=hp126).

Since half of elements for this minifigure come from Narcissa Malfoy it must have been used as a base for modifying it.

Comment: Thanks everyone, it was Narcissa Malfoy who had been mismatched but now reassembled once I knew what to look for. This can be CLOSED...APPRECIATED HARD WORK !!

Comment: @JILLYMUPPET Thanks for the confirmation - you can mark this answer as "accepted" by clicking the tick mark under the votes - You'll also [get some reputation](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/tour) for it.